# Upgrading to ActiveMQ 5.5 throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger

Tags: spring, jetty, activemq-classic

We have been using ActiveMQ 5.2 and we are looking into upgrading to ActiveMQ 5.5.

We use spring framework (2.5.6) and use Jetty (6.1.2) when running on dev mode.

I have not made any changes to applicationContext file but made classpath changes so that new jar files (activemq-core-5.5.0.jar, xbean-spring-3.7.jar) are included.

However, dev instance fails with following error message:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext-activemq.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:420)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
>     at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
>     at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
>     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
>     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
>     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:543)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:447)
>     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
>     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
>     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:543)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:421)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1035)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:783)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:275)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
>     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>     at java.beans.Introspector$1.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>     at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Unknown Source)
>     at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
>     at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
>     at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
>     at java.beans.Introspector.(Unknown Source)
>     at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanQNameHelper.getBeanInfo(XBeanQNameHelper.java:78)
>     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler.getPropertyDescriptor(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:581)
>     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler.addAttributeProperties(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:333)
>     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler.parseBeanFromExtensionElement(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:225)
>     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler.parseBeanFromExtensionElement(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:276)
>     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler.parse(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:156)
>     at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanNamespaceHandler.parse(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:49)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1297)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1287)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
>     ... 31 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload$WebAppClassLoaderExtension.findClass(JettyLauncher.java:354)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:366)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
>     ... 56 more

I tried addition additional jars (slf4j-api-1.5.11.jar) which contains the Logger interface to classpath but still got the same exception.

Queue definition of applicationContext looks like this

`

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"
    class="org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost?async=false" />
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicy"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="httpPostQueue" />
</bean>

<!-- brokers -->
<amq:broker id="broker" start="false" useJmx="false">
    <amq:destinationPolicy>
        <amq:policyMap>
            <amq:policyEntries>
                <amq:policyEntry queue="emailQueue">
                    <amq:deadLetterStrategy>
                        <amq:individualDeadLetterStrategy queuePrefix="DLQ."/>
                    </amq:deadLetterStrategy>
                </amq:policyEntry>
            </amq:policyEntries>
        </amq:policyMap>
    </amq:destinationPolicy>
    <amq:persistenceAdapter>
        <amq:jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataSource="#dataSource" useDatabaseLock="false"/>
    </amq:persistenceAdapter>
</amq:broker>`
```

What other changes do I need to make in order to upgrade ActiveMQ to 5.5?

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AMQ 5.5 uses SLF4J and provides slf4j-api in activemq-all, but your application should include one of the binders (see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder)

Comment: I actually had to add all the required jars (slf4j-api-1.5.11, slf4j-log4j12-1.5.11.jar) for slf4j in the WEB-INF/lib for Jetty. Which is a bit weird, but we had couple cases where we had to specify jar in this folder other than classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when upgrading to ActiveMQ 5.5. It turns out that ActiveMQ 5.5 uses a newer version of slf4j. We were still using 1.4.2, which is too old. In our maven pom file, I updated the slf4j dependency to:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```